# Getting this error while rendering the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-dom

I do not understand this error. 
Is this a syntax error?
Is this happening because of the react-dom version?

Throwing error on this block.

```
getWitnessName = (witnessId) => {
    if (this.props.witnesses) {
        return this.props.witnesses.find(el => el.account_id === witnessId).account_name;
    }
}
```

Error is :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'account_name' of undefined
at BlockList.__getWitnessName__REACT_HOT_LOADER__ (BlockList.js:212)
at BlockList._this.getWitnessName (BlockList.js:76)
at eval (BlockList.js:321)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at BlockList.render (BlockList.js:314)
at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17160)
at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17110)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18620)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)

The above error occurred in the <BlockList> component:
in BlockList (created by Connect(BlockList))
in Connect(BlockList) (created by Route)
in Route
in Switch
in div
in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
in ConnectedRouter
in Provider
in AppContainer
```

Comment: The error means that your `.find()` call is returning `undefined`.

Comment: There are some situations where you don't have any witness with the accountId you are looking for, so `.find()` returns `undefined` and you try to access the property `account_name` on `undefined`

Comment: This isn't a syntax error btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to validate first at to get the property, That's happening cause it's not finding any with that validation input.  Then find returns undefined, and you can't obtain property from undefined.

For example

```
this.props.witnesses.find(el => el.account_id === witnessId)?.account_name ?? 'Account Not Found';
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). OR add some code example to make it a proper answer

Comment: this.props.witnesses.find(el => el.account_id === witnessId)?.account_name ?? 'Account Not Found';

Comment: I think it's better the concept than code; cause you could code as you will if you understand why and how.

Comment: That is not how SO works. Post code, preferably tested code. It is more useful for the next visitor to see example code, like my answer which is identical to your example by the way, but has explanations of the operators since they are both very new in September 2020

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Add a [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to complete the picture instead of the normal `||` which will not react to falsy values

`return this.props.witnesses.find(el => el.account_id === witnessId)?.account_name ?? "N/A";`

It will handle missing witness and missing account_name

**Example**

```js
const props = {
  witnesses: [
  { account_id: 1, account_name: "Fred"}, 
  { account_id: 2, account_name: "Joe" }, 
  { account_id: 3 }]
};

const getName = witnessId => props.witnesses
   .find(el => el.account_id === witnessId)?.account_name ?? "N/A";

console.log(getName(1))
console.log(getName(2))
console.log(getName(3))
console.log(getName(4))
```

Comment: I understood what you mean. Thanks for ur time.

Answer (score 1):

if you see the below code the witness var can be undefined if it doesn't find any account_id matching the given witnessId. In that case, the error is being thrown so do this

```
getWitnessName = (witnessId) => {
    if (this.props.witnesses) {
        const witness = this.props.witnesses.find(el => el.account_id === witnessId)
        return witness ? witness.account_name : `No witness for given id: ${witnessId}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there s no account name?

Comment: use optional chaining `witness?.account_name || 'No Alc name '.` maybe

Comment: Yes, like in my answer

Comment: if there's account_id most probably there will be alc_name too. Any way yours cover all cases and is better. :)

Comment: I understood what you mean. Thanks for ur time.

Answer (score 0):

```
getWitnessName = (witnessId) => {
    if (this.props.witnesses) {
        let foundWitnesses = this.props.witnesses.find(el => el.account_id === witnessId);
        if(foundWitnesses)
             return foundWitnesses.account_name;
        else 
             return 'Not found';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do please use a ternary... And what if there is no account name?

Comment: In case there are more conditions i prefer using if or switch conditions. Ternary operator is better if there is only one property